# Debian Apache2 SSL Issues - Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ssl

I'm setting up apache on Debian lenny and having issues with SSL.  I've been through numberous tutorials and i had this working on Ubuntu server, but for the life of me can't get anywhere with Debian.  Port 80 (http) works fine, but port 443 (https) gives me the following error (in firefox) - homeserver is my hostname and my dhcp assigned ip is 192.168.1.109.  I have a feeling it's something with my config and not with the cert/key generation.

```
An error occurred during a connection to homeserver.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

Anyone see any issues with the following config files?

---

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName homeserver
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log combined

        Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key

        SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

---

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
Listen 443

#<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # SSL name based virtual hosts are not yet supported, therefore no
    # NameVirtualHost statement here
    #Listen 443
#</IfModule>
```

---

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       homeserver
#192.168.1.109  homeserver #tried this but it didn't work

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

---

**/etc/hostname**

```
homeserver
#192.168.1.109
```

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to enable the ssl mod..  still new at this linux/apache stuff.  this command did the trick:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old but valid and as it pops up high in searches... I would like also to remind to enable the SSL site:

```
# a2ensite
Your choices are: 000-default default-ssl
Which site(s) do you want to enable (wildcards ok)?
default-ssl
Enabling site default-ssl.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl reload apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the certificate files were wrong:
 `SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt`
 `SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key`

and did not match the actual files on the server (human error :))